# Google Create Contact Api v3 - in batch request all contacts got contactID but only few got inserted

Tags: google-api, google-apps, google-api-java-client, google-contacts-api, google-apps-marketplace

I tried to insert 4000 contacts using Google create contact api client library using batch request. Google returned 4000 google contact ids. When i try to fetch the contacts using that contact ids, observed around 1000 contacts are inserted properly and remaining are empty contacts. Even cross checked in google contacts UI and via API also. Any reasons for this problem.

Samplecode:

```
BatchUtils.setBatchId(newEntry, "create");
BatchUtils.setBatchOperationType(newEntry, BatchOperationType.INSERT);
requestFeed.getEntries().add(newEntry); //requestFeed is ContactFeed and newEntry is ContactEntry
postUrl=new URL("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/batch?xoauth_requestor_id=" + loginUser);
ContactFeed responseFeed =conService.batch(postUrl,requestFeed);
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.